# Can I take portable speakers with lithium batteries as carry-on on an Air India flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, air-india, batteries

I am travelling from Lucknow to Bengaluru. I already have my Phone (4500 mAh Lithium-ion Polymer Battery), and a power bank (2000mAh Lithium Polymer Battery) with me.

I want to carry this item [boat Stone 1500](https://www.boat-lifestyle.com/products/stone-1500) with me. The speaker has 4000 mAh battery. More details (dimension and weight) about the speaker can be also found [here](https://www.flipkart.com/boat-stone-1500-40-w-bluetooth-speaker/p/itm88c15c2adf830)

Is it allowed?

Comment: Does Air India not have published guidelines?

Comment: @jcmThey have published, but not sure If I can travel with it. Here is the guideline http://www.airindia.in/hand-luggage.htm

Comment: Anyone if downvotes should also leave comment. So next time I don't do the same stupid mistake, thanks.

Comment: Check the restricted items list as well: http://www.airindia.in/baggage-tips-and-restricted-items.htm If still unsure contact them.

Comment: @jcm I checked that page too. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Did you call Air India and asked them? It seems ok in terms and size and weight (depending on what else you are bringing) but the sizable magnets and the battery size will probably require some "interpretation" of the rules and only Air India can do that.

Comment: If your questions is about the batteries then the answer is in the http://www.airindia.in/baggage-tips-and-restricted-items.htm page linked to above. No issues carrying all three items. The powerbank needs to be properly isolated (just put some electrical tape over any connector to be sure). You need to have all in hand luggage and meet any other requirements (number, size and weight of hand luggage).

Comment: @jcaron sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Hilmar I called them,  I mailed them thrice, messaged them on twitter; they didn't reply worst service.

Comment: @jcaron Also sounds answer to me :)

Comment: @KateGregory You are correct, and I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regulations on [Air India's website](http://www.airindia.in/hand-luggage.htm) are very clear. The relevant parts are :

*"for lithium ion batteries the Watt-hour rating must not exceed 100 Wh"*

*"Batteries spare / loose, including lithium ion cells or batteries, for portable electronic devices must be carried in carry-on baggage only" and "Articles which have the primary purpose as a power source, e.g. power banks are considered as spare batteries"*

*"Each person is limited to a maximum of 20 spare batteries"*

You have stated that all of your devices have Lithium-Ion based batteries that are 4500 mAh or less.  To convert mAh (milliamp-hours) to Wh (watt-hours) you need to divide by 1000, and multiply by the internal voltage of the battery, which for Li-ion batteries is ~3.6 volts.  Thus 4500 mAh is 4500/1000*3.6 = ~16 Wh - well below the allowed 100 Wh per battery.

Your power bank is clearly considered a "spare battery" per the rules. Even if your speaker is also considered a spare battery (which is unlikely, but possible), then you have 2 spare batteries - well below the 20 allowed.

So yes, it is allowed.